# Why does this regex not match everything till recurrence of first capture group?

Tags: python, regex, multiline, citations, multilinestring

And how do I make it do that?

Right now it stops at line breaks (like right after "Chicago,").
Alternatively, if I use DOTALL it just matches "Abbott A (1988)" and then the rest of the string till the very end. 
I would like it to stop at the next occurrence of (([\w\s]+)(([1|2]\d{3}))), that is ... "Albu OB and Flyverbom M (2016)". And so on and so forth.

Any pointers welcome.

```
pattern = r"(([\w\s]+)\(([1|2]\d{3})\))(.*)"
```

sample string

```
"Abbott A (1988) The System of Professions: An Essay on the Division of Expert Labor. Chicago,
IL: University of Chicago Press.
Albu OB and Flyverbom M (2016) Organizational transparency: conceptualizations, con-
ditions, and consequences. Business & Society. Epub ahead of print 13 July. DOI:
10.1177/0007650316659851.
Ananny M (2016) Toward an ethics of algorithms: convening, observation, probability, and timeli-
ness. Science, Technology & Human Values 41(1): 93–117. DOI: 10.1177/0162243915606523."
```

sandbox [here](https://regex101.com/r/LqGUlO/8)

Comment: because you do not use multiline flag?

Comment: i did. it's on in the sandbox, sorry it's not written down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?sm)^([^()\n\r]+)\(([12]\d{3})\)(.*?)(?=^[^()\n\r]+\([12]\d{3}\)|\Z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LX4bee/2)

**Details**

- `(?sm)` - `re.DOTALL` and `re.MULTILINE` enabled
- `^` - start of a line
- `([^()\n\r]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `(`, `)`, CR and LF
- `\(` - a `(`
- `([12]\d{3})` - Group 2: `1` or `2` and then any 3 digits
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 3: any 0+ chars, including line breaks, as few as possible, up to (but excluding from match) the first...
- `(?=^[^()\r\n]+\([12]\d{3}\)|\Z)` - (a positive lookahead that requires the presence of its pattern immediately to the right of the current location):

  - `^[^()\r\n]+\([12]\d{3}\)` - same as the start of the pattern but with no groups
  - `|` - or
  - `\Z` - end of the whole text.

Comment: i have added a comma, like this

(?sm)^([\w\s,]+)\(([12]\d{3})\)(.*?)(?=^[\w\s,]+\([12]\d{3}\)|\Z)

to include those references with multiple authors

Comment: @treakec I have suggested fixing that with `[^()\n\r]+` (there are more than commas, dots are there, too). It i matches any char but `(`, `)` or a common line break char.

Comment: yes, great idea. it will also come in handy later, i think. thanks.